# Continuous function and an interval

Tags: functions

How to prove that if  $f: [a,b] \to [f(a),f(b)]$ is nondecreasing and continuous function, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is an interval for any $y \in [f(a),f(b)] $

Comment: Define $c=\inf f^{-1}(y)$ and $d=\sup f^{-1}(y)$ and prove that $t\in f^{-1}(y)$ for every $t\in(c,d)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a single point, it is an interval and we're done.

If not, suppose that $x_1,x_2$ belong to $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. As $f$ is nondecreasing, we have for $x_1 < x < x_2$: $$y=f(x_1) \le f(x) \le f(x_2)=y.$$ Hence $f(x)=y$, which proves that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is convex. As the convex subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the intervals, we get the conclusion.